# Types of responses can get from Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

When certain characters are entered into a Google Forms descriptive question, the answer is retrieved from the event as an exponent (e.g. "3E8" -> "3.00E+08")

How do I get input data as a string?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation,

About `When certain characters are entered into a Google Forms descriptive question, the answer is retrieved from the event as an exponent (e.g. "3E8" -> "3.00E+08")`, in this case, I guessed that when you saw the Spreadsheet the submitted data from Google Form, the inputted value of `3E8` might be changed to `3.00E+08`.

If my understanding is correct, in the current stage, when the inputted value like `3E8` is submitted, it seems that the value is changed to `3.00E+08` on the Spreadsheet side. And, when I checked the submitted values of the event object with Google Spreadsheet, the value had already been changed from `3E8` to `3.00E+08`. It seems that this might be the current specification on the Google side. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug.

But, fortunately, when I checked the submitted values on the Google Form side, I confirmed that the value of `3E8` is stored as `3E8`.

From `How do I get input data as a string?`, in this answer, I would like to propose directly retrieving the values from Google Form and putting the values to the Spreadsheet as the string value. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Form. And, please set the Google Spreadsheet ID and the sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Google Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name of sheet you want to put the values.

  // Retrieve all response values from Google Form.
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const headers = ["date", ...form.getItems().map(e => e.getTitle())];
  const values = [headers, ...form.getResponses().map((f) => {
    const timeStamp = f.getTimestamp();
    return f.getItemResponses().reduce((o, i) => {
      const r = i.getResponse();
      return Object.assign(o, {
        [i.getItem().getTitle()]: Array.isArray(r) ? r.join(",") : r,
      });
    }, { date: timeStamp });
  }).map((o) => headers.map((t) => o[t] || ""))];

  // Put the values to Spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, all response values are retrieved and the values are put as the string type to Google Spreadsheet.
- If you want to put the values when the Google Form is submitted, how about the following sample script? Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Form. And, please set the Google Spreadsheet ID and the sheet name. And, [please install OnSubmit trigger to `onSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually). By this, when Google Form is submitted, this function is automatically run by the OnSubmit trigger. So, please don't directly run this function by the script editor.

  ```js
  function onSubmit(e) {
    const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Google Spreadsheet ID.
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name of sheet you want to put the values.

    const f = e.response;
    const timeStamp = f.getTimestamp();
    const values = [timeStamp, ...f.getItemResponses().map(e => {
      const r = e.getResponse();
      return Array.isArray(r) ? r.join(",") : r;
    })];
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, values.length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues([values]);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Putting All Response Values from Google Form to Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/10/15/putting-all-response-values-from-google-form-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/)