# Google forms onSubmit trigger e.namedValues undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form submit trigger configured from apps script like this:
[image]

The `onSubmit` function is this:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  console.log("Form submitted", JSON.stringify(e.namedValues));
  console.log("Form submitted", JSON.stringify(e));

}
```

But whenever I submit the form, the trigger does get fired and function runs. But `e.namedValues` is undefined.

[image]

What could be wrong? (I have linked a spreadsheet to the form which also did not change the outcome).

Comment: Although @[Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091) is correct, I also believe this Stack Overflow post would answer your question. Can you confirm? [Google Apps Script Form: e.namedValues logs nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731075)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Google Forms: Retrieve Responses Automatically

This sample script allows you to retrieve responses submitted to your Google Form automatically in the `Executions` tab of Google Apps Script.

> *Note: This may be similar to @[Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091)'s approach in his last comment.*

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  var formResponse = {};

  itemResponses.forEach(itemResponses => {
    var itemTitle = itemResponses.getItem().getTitle();
    var value = itemResponses.getResponse();
    formResponse[itemTitle] = value;
  });
  console.log("Answer submitted: " + JSON.stringify(formResponse));
}
```

The sample form looks like this:

[image]

#### OUTPUT

[image]

#### REFERENCE

- [Class Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)
- [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

Comment: Feel free to clarify if I've misunderstood what your goal is. I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Answer (score 4):

The source should  be from Spreadsheet.

There is no namedValues on the trigger for the form.

- [There's two onFormSubmit Triggers on this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes now I realised that the form submit event for form trigger does not have a namedValues. However the e.response is also empty. so what could be wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253706/how-to-extract-response-items-from-a-google-form/26285341#26285341

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77185441/types-of-responses-can-get-from-google-forms/77185971#77185971

Comment: I don't use the trigger from the form very much but here is a simple example of the code to get the response from a very simple form: `function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  let a = e.response.getItemResponses().map((ir,i) => {
    let itm = ir.getItem()
    return [itm.getIndex(),itm.getTitle(),itm.getType(),ir.getResponse().valueOf(),e.response.getTimestamp()]
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a))
}`